# Eliminating the value of a field on a Postgres Trigger

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a Postgres trigger that will eliminate a whole field from NEW like in (because this column will be filled automatically by the database and I do not want to change the assigned value by the database):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION befo_insert_for_auto_inc_numeric_ids()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
NEW.Id = NULL;   <---- Want to eliminate Id field from NEW
RETURN NEW;
END;

$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is wrong with setting it to NULL?

Comment: hmm... is that enough?

Comment: Enough for what?

Comment: the column is autoincrement, and I do not want to insert a NULL value in it

Comment: Then don't change it - it will contain the autoincrement value.

Comment: So, it means that by assigning NEW.ID=NULL the database will automatically assign an auto-incremented value?

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga: no, if you set it to `null` you are effectively **overwriting** the default value.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to revoke the `INSERT`/`UPDATE` column permissions on that field. No need for a trigger.

Comment: but, will the other columns continue be filled? If someone tries to write on that auto-in column, I will need this to be stopped but allow the writing in the other columns

Comment: Declare the column as `generated always as identity` then you'll get an error during insert if you try to bypass the generator

Comment: By setting it to `NULL`, you are explicitly telling the database, "I want a NULL as this column value." Since you cannot assign to the keyword `DEFAULT` in this context in a trigger, @a_horse_with_no_name has it exactly right. You want `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` and to catch where errant apps are misbehaving.

Comment: But I will still need the other fields for the INSERT to be filled up. I need to able to ignore that id column info but allow the other fields in the INSERT operation to go through. So, a new row will be created anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `NULL` to the column will achieve the opposite of what you want: if will manually set the column's value to NULL which will fail if the column is defined as `NOT NULL`

If you want to make sure that the ID is generated always regardless of what was provided in the in the actual INSERT statement, you can use `nextval()` inside the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert_for_auto_inc_numeric_ids()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
  NEW.id := nextval('id_column_seq');
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Replace `id_column_seq` with the name of the sequence attached to that column.

Note that this will most probably cause confusion at some point because values passed in the INSERT statement might not be the value stored in the table.

Comment: This is very close... In the past it was being used string ids and now we wanted to change to int auto increment ids. Some controllers were sending strings for id but I wanted to ignore this and just use the auto inc int column feature. At present I am getting an error related to the data type. Could this error be ignored also?

Comment: I have no idea what error you are talking about, but if `id` is not an integer, then this will indeed throw an error. You can't have an "auto increment" on a data type that is not a number. If you don't want to use integers (or bigint) and sequences, use a `uuid`

Comment: The table data type remains auto inc. The controller was sending strings... so I needed to also ignore this.

Comment: Then tell your controller (if that is a person) write correct SQL statements.

Comment: We have a very nice code that uses strings for ids and it is working for several existing tables. We did not wanted to remake this code for new tables that are using the auto inc integer ids. I thought we could try ignoring use of those string ids on isert and still use the existing controllers code.

Comment: That is a completely different question now.